# manipulate PHP domdocument string

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to remove the element tag in my domdocument html.

I have something like

```
this is the <a href='#'>test link</a> here and <a href='#'>there</a>.
```

I want to change my html to

```
this is the test link here and there.
```

My code

```
 $dom = new DomDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 $atags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

 foreach($atags as $atag){
     $value = $atag->nodeValue;
//I can get the test link and there value but I don't know how to remove the a tag.                              
     }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are looking for a method called [`DOMNode::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/DOMNode.replaceChild).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a method called [`DOMNode::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/DOMNode.replaceChild).

To make use of that you need to create a `DOMText` of the `$value` ([`DOMDocument::createTextNode()`](http://php.net/DOMDocument.createTextNode)) and also `getElementsByTagName` return a self-updating list, so when you replace the first element and then you go to the second, there is no second any longer, there is only one a element left.

Instead you need a while on the first item:

```
$atags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
while ($atag = $atags->item(0))
{
    $node = $dom->createTextNode($atag->nodeValue);
    $atag->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $atag);
}
```

Something along those lines should do it.

Comment: I've tried [almost the same](http://3v4l.org/Wddra) but wondered why only the first `<a>` tag will be replaced while yours is working. The type of while loop you are using did the trick! nice

Comment: @hek2mgl: Yes, that's the one note I wrote: lists by getElementsByTagName are automatically updating to all current elements with that tagname. If you remove one element of those, the list changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `strip_tags` - it should do what you've asked.

```
<?php

$string = "this is the <a href='#'>test link</a> here and <a href='#'>there</a>.";

echo strip_tags($string);

// output: this is the test link here and there.
```